# cassandra 1.2 error in startup with ssl enabled

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 1.2 datastax community edition. I am trying to enable the client_encryption_options and the server is not starting up. I am getting the below exception.

cassnadra.yaml configuration

```
client_encryption_options: 
enabled: true 
keystore: C:/Projects/MainApp/cassandrakeystore.jks
keystore_password: cassandra 
require_client_auth: true 
# Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true 
truststore: C:/Projects/MainApp/cassandratruststore.jks 
truststore_password: cassandra
```

Exception on the startup

```
    ERROR [main] 2014-07-08 10:41:09,006 CassandraDaemon.java (line 464) Exception encountered during startup
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create thrift socket to localhost/127.0.0.1:9160
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.TServerCustomFactory.buildTServer(TServerCustomFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer$ThriftServerThread.<init>(ThriftServer.java:105)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftServer.start(ThriftServer.java:52)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.start(CassandraDaemon.java:400)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:460)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:490)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 9160
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:103)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CustomTThreadPoolServer$Factory.buildTServer(CustomTThreadPoolServer.java:257)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:113)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: What is the SSL engine at the server?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, the following line makes me think you need to install JCE:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers

See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html